# jsRender - build 54 - render not defined

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

updated to build 54, every time I attempt to render, I get a "undefined" error.  This is the function I am calling:

```
var div = $(template).render(_content);
```

If I rollback to build 53 everything works.   Did a code diff between jsrender.js build 53 & build 54 and noticed on line 72 in build 53, the declaration `render: $render,` is missing from build 54.  Is there a syntax change I didn't see in the online doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax

```
var renderedHtml = $("#myTmpl").render(myData);
```

works correctly in build 54.

See  http://www.jsviews.com/#db.render.

The intention of the `$(xxx).render(myData)` API is that xxx is either an HTML element or a selector - referencing in both cases a script element containing your template markup.

If you have already compiled your template, e.g. from a string, then you should use the syntax `myCompiledTemplate.render(myData)`. (See http://www.jsviews.com/#tmplrender).

In build 53, writing `$(myCompiledTemplate).render(data)` was (spuriously) equivalent to the correct `myCompiledTemplate.render(data)` - but it was not performant (unnecessary instantiation of a jQuery object) and was incorrect usage. That syntax is not supported...

Here is your updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5vFd/2/

Comment: OK - here's my fiddle running against 54 http://jsfiddle.net/w5vFd/1/   I get a "undefined is not a function".   If I run this exact code against 53 it works